# The header time_types.h in linux folder is not found when compiling a module

Tags: c, linux, module

To start building a block-drive (it is called "out of tree"?) module, I'm trying to compile just some headers from Linux.

Edit: Deleted .c file and renamed .h file to .c, but the same 1 error persists.

BlockVRAM.c:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
```

Makefile:

```
BINARY     := BlockVRAM
KERNEL      := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
ARCH        := x86
C_FLAGS     := -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/include/ -I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/arch/x86/include
KMOD_DIR    := $(shell pwd)
TARGET_PATH := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel/drivers/char

OBJECTS := BlockVRAM.o

CC += $(C_FLAGS)

obj-m := $(BINARY).o

$(BINARY)-y := $(OBJECTS)

$(BINARY).ko:
    make ARCH=x86 -C $(KERNEL) M=$(KMOD_DIR) modules

install:
    cp $(BINARY).ko $(TARGET_PATH)
    depmod -a

clean:
    rm -f *.ko
    rm -f *.o
```

There is only 1 error it is returning:

```
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/include/linux/time64.h:10:0,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/include/linux/restart_block.h:10,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/include/linux/thread_info.h:13,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/include/linux/preempt.h:78,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/include/linux/seqlock.h:36,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/include/linux/time.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/include/linux/stat.h:19,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from BlockVRAM.h:12,
                 from BlockVRAM.c:11:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic/include/uapi/linux/time.h:6:10: fatal error: linux/time_types.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/time_types.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'BlockVRAM' failed
make: *** [BlockVRAM] Error 1
```

I tried to include that folder as an include flag but it only caused re-definition errors. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Using Makefile as this:

```
sudo make BlockVRAM
```

in same folder of source file.

I started from [here](https://olegkutkov.me/2020/02/10/linux-block-device-driver/) but there were a lot of errors until I added those two include directory flags in Makefile.

Comment: Why do you have main and stdio.h in a kernel module?

Comment: Do you want to build a kernel module? How exactly do try to you build it? What commands do you use? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: @stark that's just to run it from command line to see that it compiled but do you mean stdio and main are not allowed in out-of-tree modules, even for just trying to compile?

Comment: Shouldn't `make BlockVRAM` be `make BlockVRAM.ko`? It still won't work, but at least it will try and build a kernel module instead of an executable program.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, very little of the C standard library can be used in kernel modules, and stdio.h in particular cannot be used.  Or at least, the functions it declares cannot be used, and you cannot rely on the header itself to be available.  Furthermore, `main` does not make sense in a kernel module, and it might not have the meaning you think it will.  This is all part of the difference between code that is intended to run on top of an operating system and code that is intended to run without (or as) an OS.

Comment: I deleted .c source file, renamed .h file to .c, same 1 error happened.

Comment: I recommend looking at one of the many online tutorials for building a simple "hello world" type kernel module.

Comment: As soon as I include "<linux/module.h>", same error happens.

Comment: Why follow someone's blog when the kernel contains the correct instructions for building an external module  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/kbuild/modules.rst

Comment: @stark Nice, html version of the above: [Building External Modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html).

Comment: Ok, "make -f ./Makefile" worked.